# Difference between stack and listview in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter

I recently came to see that when displaying a list of widgets, `stack` and `listView` don't work the same way.
here is an example :

With this code the I got list of two items of `listData` widget ( a custom widget )

```
new ListView(

          children: <Widget>[

       new Container(
         child: ListData(
             margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
             width: screenSize.width,
             title: "Breakfast with Harry",
             subtitle: "9 - 10am ",
             image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/avatar-1.jpg'),
               fit: BoxFit.cover,))
       ),
       new Container(
           child: ListData(
               margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
               width: screenSize.width,
               title: "Breakfast with Harry",
               subtitle: "9 - 10am ",
               image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/avatar-1.jpg'),
                 fit: BoxFit.cover,))
       ),

          ],
          )
```

When replacing `ListView` with `stack`

```
new Stack(

          children: <Widget>[

       new Container(
         child: ListData(
             margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
             width: screenSize.width,
             title: "Breakfast with Harry",
             subtitle: "9 - 10am ",
             image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/avatar-1.jpg'),
               fit: BoxFit.cover,))
       ),
       new Container(
           child: ListData(
               margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
               width: screenSize.width,
               title: "Breakfast with Harry",
               subtitle: "9 - 10am ",
               image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/avatar-1.jpg'),
                 fit: BoxFit.cover,))
       ),

          ],
          )
```

I get only one item, and from the inspector it seems all the items are on top of each other.

Isn't `stack` and `listview` supposed to work the same way ?

Answer (score 6):

> Isn't stack and listview supposed to work the same way?

No, not at all. `Stack` and `ListView` are *very* different.

- `ListView` is for a vertical/horizontal scrollable list. It is similar to `Row`/`Column` but its content is scrollable.
- `Stack` is to freely position multiple widgets under the same parent. It's commonly used to stack widgets on the top of each other.